# Create custom tag extending XSLT using .NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, extension-objects

Is there a way to create custom tag extending XSLT in a similar way to custom function?

ie (in my xslt file):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
  <my:customTag items="3" classname="foo"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

expected output:

```
<div>
  <ul class="foo">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
  <xsl:copy-of select="my:customFunc(3,'foo')" />
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

and my customFunc in vb code do something like this:

```
Public Function customFunc(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal classname as String) As System.Xml.XmlNode
            Dim newNode As System.Xml.XmlNode
            Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
            Dim xmlContent As String = "<ul class=""" + classname + """>"

            For v As Integer = 0 To n
                xmlContent += "<li>" + someComplicatedCalc(n) + "</li>"
            Next
            xmlContent += "</ul>"


            doc.LoadXml(xmlContent)
            newNode = doc.DocumentElement

            Return newNode
        End Function
```

but I want to use tags instead of functions.

Comment: What does "using tags instead of functions" mean?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call your function from xslt?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my post, take a look at it. I want to call my function but using a tag like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any support for this feature called custom [extension elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#extension-element) with Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` and other processors, like XmlPrime or like Saxon (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/extensibility/instructions.html) don't seem to support it either with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to replace your VB function with just XSLT, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="my:customTag">
    <ul class="{@classname}">
      <xsl:call-template name="expand_customTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="@items" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="expand_customTag">
    <xsl:param name="i" />
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <il>....</il>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count">
      <xsl:call-template name="expand_customTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The idea is using a recursive template to produce your `<il>` elements, and this would make your XSLT more portable to other XSLT processors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your existing VB.Net code but have nicer syntax in your source XML try adding this template to your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:template match="my:customTag">
  <xsl:copy-of select="my:customFunc(@items,@classname)" />
</xsl:template>
```

The xpath selector will use your `<my:customTag items="3" classname="foo"/>`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to insert the custom tag in my XSLT, not in my XML.

Comment: Are you trying to output a custom tag or use XSLT extension elements?

Comment: I'm trying to use XSLT extension element, but with no luck. Basically I want the customTag to be replaced with its vb output during xslt transformation.